# How would I get my streamlit application to use a flask API in order to retrieve data?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, streamlit

So I am currently new to working with a flask api and I am just wondering how I can connect a streamlit application to the flask api? Like I would want the streamlit application to be using the flask api that then pulls the database. Currently, my streamlit application is in a folder and it contains a dockerfile. And I have my flask api in a separate folder.

```
Main Folder
   Flask-API Folder
      - main.py
      - requirements.txt
      - table1.db
   Streamlit application Folder
      - app.py
      - Dockerfile
      - more python files
      - requirements.txt
```

For example, if like a user clicked on a check box that produced a graph on streamlit, how can I get the streamlit application to go into the flask-api folder(contact the api) and get/pull the database. I am just wondering what I would have to add to my main.py file in my flask-api folder.

Note: The purpose as to why I am trying to get the streamlit application to contact the flask api is because right now, the streamlit application is contacting another API instead and it takes a while for the graphs to be produced.

Answer (score 5):

Finally figured it out. All I had to do in my app.py file was use the `request` package.

```
#app.py
import streamlit as st
import request
import pandas as pd

# http://127.0.01:5000/ is from the flask api
response = request.get("http://127.0.01:5000/")
print(response.json())
data_table1 = pd.DataFrame(response.json())
st.write(data_table1)
```

Comment: Hi SL42. I'm trying to connect flask and streamlit just like you. I tried your own answer by fixing typos. But keep getting error messages like 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'. Did your project work without any error if you did can you give me some advice?

Comment: Hi @2asy, the project did work without any error. My guess as to why you are getting this error is that the data is not being read in correctly or the data is formatted differently.